# Apache POI jar has no hwpf package

Tags: java, apache-poi, hwpf

I have downloaded the poi api jar files from [this link](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/poi/release/bin/poi-bin-3.8-20120326.zip)'s first [mirror link](http://apache.petsads.us/poi/release/bin/poi-bin-3.8-20120326.zip),which is suggested.

After downloaded I saw that **org.apache.poi.hwpf** package is not present there. Actually my work is completely depends on that API. So can anybody please tell me the proper link to download **hwpf API**.

Actually my work is to read a MS Word file with some text as well as some table and then edit the values of the table rows. If any other API is also suitable for this kind of work, you please suggest me with their links to download.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As described in the [Apache POI Components page](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components), the HWPF package is available in the "scratchpad" JAR: poi-scratchpad-3.8-20120326.jar

Please note, that the scratchpad features are not particularly mature and should be used with care.