# How to set background color (Page Color) for word document (.doc or .docx) in Java?

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi, background-color

By some libraries like http://poi.apache.org , we could create **word document** with any text color, but for **background** or highlight of the text, I didn't find any solution.

Page color for word in manual way!:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-background-or-color-of-a-document-6ce0b23e-b833-4421-b8c3-b3d637e62524

Here is my main code to create word document by poi.apache

```
        // Blank Document
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
        // Write the Document in file system
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(file_address));
        // create Paragraph
        XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
        paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.RIGHT);

        XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
        run.setFontFamily(font_name);
        run.setFontSize(font_size);
        // This only set text color not background!
        run.setColor(hex_color);

        for (String s : text_array) {
            run.setText(s);
            run.addCarriageReturn();
        }

        document.write(out);
        out.close();
```

Comment: Please find stcakoverflow answer 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35419619/how-can-i-set-background-colour-of-a-run-a-word-in-line-or-a-paragraph-in-a-do

Comment: @LearNer Thanks! Usually beginners are more responsive in this site!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We Only need to add these 3 lines to set the background color for Word documents by XWPF. We have to set these lines after declaring XWPFRun and it's text color:

```
CTShd cTShd = run.getCTR().addNewRPr().addNewShd();
cTShd.setVal(STShd.CLEAR);
cTShd.setFill(hex_background_color);
```

Comment: For the record: A much more elaborate version of this XWPF-based approach can be found in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35508229/5717099).

Answer (score 3):

***Update: XWPF is the newest way to create word document files, but setting background only possible by HWPF which is for old format version (.doc)***

**For *.doc (i.e. POI's HWPF component):**

1. Highlighting of text:
   Look into [`setHighlighted()`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hwpf/usermodel/CharacterRun.html#setHighlighted%28byte%29)
2. Background color:

   *I suppose you mean the background of a paragraph (AFAIK, Word also allows to color the entire page which is a different matter)*

   There is [`setShading()`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hwpf/usermodel/Paragraph.html#setShading%28org.apache.poi.hwpf.usermodel.ShadingDescriptor%29) which allows you to provide a foreground and background color (through `setCvFore()` and `setCvBack()` of `SHDAbstractType`) for a Paragraph. IIRC, it is the *foreground* that you would want to set in order to color your Paragraph. The *background* is only relevant for shadings which are composed of two (alternating) colors.

   The underlying data structure is named `Shd80` ([MS-DOC], 2.9.248). There is also `SHDOperand` ([MS-DOC], 2.9.249) that reflects the functionality of Word prior to Word97. [MS-DOC] is the Binary Word File format specification which is freely available on MSDN.

**Edit:**

Here is some code to illustrate the above:

```
    try {
        HWPFDocument document = [...]; // comes from somewhere
        Range range = document.getRange();

        // Background shading of a paragraph
        ParagraphProperties pprops = new ParagraphProperties();
        ShadingDescriptor shd = new ShadingDescriptor();
        shd.setCvFore(Colorref.valueOfIco(0x07)); // yellow; ICO
        shd.setIpat(0x0001); // solid background; IPAT
        pprops.setShading(shd);
        Paragraph p1 = range.insertBefore(pprops, StyleSheet.NIL_STYLE);
        p1.insertBefore("shaded paragraph");

        // Highlighting of individual characters
        Paragraph p2 = range.insertBefore(new ParagraphProperties(), StyleSheet.NIL_STYLE);     
        CharacterRun cr = p2.insertBefore("highlighted text\r");
        cr.setHighlighted((byte) 0x06); // red; ICO

        document.write([...]); // document goes to somewhere
    } catch (IOException e) {   
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

- [`ICO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd773060%28v=office.12%29.aspx) is a color structure
- [`IPAT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd945712%28v=office.12%29.aspx) is a list of predefined shading styles

Comment: Unfortunately, they only introduce methods by JavaDoc not real example!
Could you answer me by code?
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-background-or-color-of-a-document-6ce0b23e-b833-4421-b8c3-b3d637e62524

Comment: So you actually want to change the background of your document and not that of individual paragraphs?

Comment: yes! But that's paragraph is also good enough if that page color isn't possible. :)

Comment: Ok, I've added an example of the old Word format since this is what I started off with. Hope this helps. Coloring of the entire page is currently not possible using HWPF (would have to be handled on the [Section](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hwpf/usermodel/Section.html)-level).

Comment: But I cannot figure out "getRange" function! Could you give me a clear instruction about importing libraries? I tried to import some other libraries but it didn't worked. for example: import org.apache.poi.hwpf.usermodel.Range;

Comment: @bdshahab For HWPF you need to have both the core POI library and poi-scatchpad on your classpath. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10125136/apache-poi-jar-has-no-hwpf-package).

Comment: I have this jar library:
poi-3.13
which also has "poi-scatchpad-3.13-20150929.jar"
But I cannot run your code, especially this line:
Range range = document.getRange();
It's better to tell me which version of poi library you using and what you imported!
My import was these but still it doesn't work!
import org.apache.*;
import org.apache.poi.*;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.*;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.usermodel.Range;
and some other but it was useless!

Comment: @bdshahab `HWPFDocument.getRange()` is a fundamental function of HWPF. I can see it in [trunk](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/scratchpad/src/org/apache/poi/hwpf/HWPFDocument.java), so it shouldn't really matter which version of POI you are using for this to work. Are you sure both the poi and the poi-scratchpad jar are on your classpath?

Comment: @mondo I'm sure! I also downloaded poi-scratchpad-3.2-FINAL.jar independently and imported that too, which also has the same libraries which exist in main poi-3.13
Look at this picture I take from my libraries:
http://oi66.tinypic.com/2ug2jjo.jpg

Comment: @bdshahab [Don't use two scratchpads concurrently!](https://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N1019C) - Besides that: What is the exact error you are getting? Do you have `import org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument;` and `import org.apache.poi.hwpf.usermodel.Range;` in the respective source file? Eclipse (which you are obviously using) should either add those lines automatically or offer a quick fix to do so.

Comment: @mondo I imported many of them and also those you suggested but still it doesn't recognize! I think it's better to show me a complete source code with the latest version of poi.apache.org. Here is the picture from my code which shows getRange() still is an error: http://oi65.tinypic.com/szx01j.jpg

Comment: @bdshahab Once again: What is the exact error your are getting? So what does Eclipse say when you hover that `document.getRange()` line? Your HWPFDocument.java should look exactly like [this](https://github.com/apache/poi/blob/d5ee899d89e7db107750b3fe9e8b096187596048/src/scratchpad/src/org/apache/poi/hwpf/HWPFDocument.java) (you can confirm this by doing a CTRL+Click on `HWPFDocument` in Eclipse) and thus has the necessary `getRange()` method.
Did you import the correct Range and not accidentally a class with the same name from some other unrelated package?

Comment: @mondo When I hover on it, it says: "The method getRange() is undefined for the type XWPFDocument". I also imported all that libraries you linked but still it doesn't recognize getRange(). I'm using Java 8 and poi-3.13. I think it's better to show me a simple working source code for this problem! with respect! :)

Comment: All of my imports for poi.apache:
org.apache.poi.hwpf.model.Colorref;
org.apache.poi.hwpf.model.StyleSheet;
org.apache.poi.hwpf.usermodel.CharacterRun;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.usermodel.Paragraph;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.usermodel.ParagraphProperties;
org.apache.poi.hwpf.usermodel.Range;
org.apache.poi.hwpf.usermodel.ShadingDescriptor;
org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.ParagraphAlignment;
org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;
org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun;
org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STOnOff;

Comment: @bdshahab My code is for **HWPF** not XWPF (see the very first line of my initial answer)! Hence, we are dealing with an `HWPFDocument` and not an `XWPFDocument`. AFAIK the particular functionality you asked for (background + highlighting) is not available with XWPF. Or to but it bluntly: You can only do this for a `*.doc` file and not for `*.docx`.

Comment: @mondo Thanks! So I have to ignore background color until they provide it! :)

Comment: @bdshabab Your question was initially open regarding the file format (see your question title). If you had pointed out in the beginning that you need this explicitly for `*.docx`, you would have saved me from quite a bit of (apparently useless) work. So please be more specific next time! Other than that, I believe it wouldn't be too difficult to add your required functionality to XWPF - so consider crafting a patch. POI is open-source, after all.

Comment: @mondo sorry about that! But your answer wasn't useless. Honestly, I'm beginner to work by these libraries (poi.apache) and I didn't know there is another way like HWPF. I saw a clear example in their site which illustrated by XWPF. (next time I hope, I could explain better, my friend! :) )