# Simple POI background fill issue

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm using poi 3.14 and all I want is to set the background of the cell to be orange.  I don't want a pattern filled, just a solid orange, and yet I cannot get it to work.  Here's what I have:

```
    Row row = sheet.createRow(currentRow);

    CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
    style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.AUTOMATIC.getIndex());
    style.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.ORANGE.getIndex());
    style.setFillPattern(CellStyle.ALIGN_FILL);

    Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
    cell.setCellValue("ABCDEFG");
    cell.setCellStyle(style);
```

What I end up with is an orange background with `small dots` pattern.  On Excel's property sheet, it says I have `bg=orange, fg=automatic, pattern=25% Gray`.  How can I use simply a blank pattern style?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems unintuitive first but the `setFillForegroundColor` method actually sets the foreground color of the background fill not the text (which comes to mind first as foreground). Similarly, you need to use `CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND` for the fill pattern. See below for a working version.

```
Row row = sheet.createRow(currentRow);

CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.ORANGE.getIndex());
style.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
cell.setCellValue("ABCDEFG");
cell.setCellStyle(style);
```

You may refer to the poi user guide for more examples: http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FillsAndFrills .

Comment: Thank you, I don't know why I didn't try this combination, but like you said, it is unintuitive.  I think the implementation is essentially wrong (i.e. reversed).  as it doesn't match what is shown in Excel.  Text has always been foreground.  setFillPattern seems to be used differently according to the referenced example depending on whether background or foreground is being set.

Comment: @ergonaut No, background/foreground aren't messed up in POI. Microsoft is the one to be blamed for this strange wording: Shadings can be composed of two colors (i.e. "background" *and* "foreground") + a value that indexes different patterns. Word implements essentially the same behavior, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34544181/5717099).